# Shipping class formula help: If quantity is 1-3, charge X amount?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am selling prints in my store. I print them and ship them off in tubes. Each tube can hold up to three prints and the cost to send one tube is X amount.

How can I write:

If quantity is 1-3, charge X…
If the quantity is 4-6, charge 2X…
If the quantity is 7-9, charge 3X…

Etc, etc.?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> woocommerce_package_rates

hook to manipulate the shipping costs.

```
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates ) {

//Assuming charge X you mentioned is 5
$custom_shipping_cost = 5;
$total_items = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

if($total_items > 3 && $total_items < 7) $custom_shipping_cost *= 2;
else if ($total_items > 6 && $total_items < 10) $custom_shipping_cost *= 3;
else if ($total_items > 9 && $total_items < 13) $custom_shipping_cost *= 4;
//you may add more else if statements here
//or try this which is smarter I believe:
/*
* $multiplier = floor( $total_items / 4 ) + 1;
* $custom_shipping_cost *= $multiplier;
*/

foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) 
{
    $rates[$key]->cost = $custom_shipping_cost;
}

return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates' );
```

Hope this helps. Code goes to functions.php of your theme or child-theme (which is better).